# Insert line before last line in a large size .DAT file in java

Tags: java

I have a large (around 50k+ lines). DAT file. I need to add one line before the last line in it.

When I am using:

```
Files.write(path, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

It is appending line after the last line.

Is there any way I can insert the line before the last line?

Comment: How about to use binary mode?

Comment: `.DAT` means to me a data file. A data file is usually not a text file and a file that is not a text file does not have lines. Does your file contain text only? Can I open your file in a text editor, like [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Notepad) or [vim](https://www.vim.org/) and read its contents?

Comment: Yes. This file can be open in Notepad++, and the file is having readable text

Comment: @ghchoi : can you elaborate more?